# Objective C - Pick random NIB file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xib, nib

Hello I would like to have my app pick a randome XIB file to choose from, and exclude 3 of them.

```
    HowToPlay *LetsPlay = [[HowToPlay alloc] initWithNibName:@"HowToPlay" bundle:nil];

LetsPlay.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:LetsPlay animated:YES];

[LetsPlay release];
```

So i know how to load from a nib file by doing the above, but i would like it to be able to pick a random one and then exclude certain ones.

The ones i want excluded:
MainViewController,
FlipSideViewController,
HowToPlay

Ones i want:
Question 1,
Question 2,
and so on....

Any ideas of how i can do this?

Thanks!. Have a great day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the nib names you want (represented as `NSString`) in a `NSArray`, then generate a random number and pick up one nib name from the array.